# Error in setting eventhubs.checkpoint.dir in spark streaming job from event hub

Tags: apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I am trying to access event hub data by running a spark streaming job locally. 
I faced an issue in  setting the event hub configuration for `eventhubs.checkpoint.dir` . I tried setting below value

- `wasbs://container_name@storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/`
- `https://container_name@storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/`
- `https://storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/continer_name/`

Each resulted in similar errors as the following one:

```
ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Error handling message; restarting receiver -   java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
```

Comment: Could you please guide me in understanding "eventhubs.checkpoint.dir"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set eventhubs.checkpoint.dir to a string value that would be a valid wasb folder name.  For instance, I set it to "/myeventhubspark".  The folder will be automatically created in the default container of your Spark cluster.  Be sure to prepend the folder name with a forward-slash , like this -

"eventhubs.checkpoint.dir" -> "/myeventhubspark"

Comment: thanks for the response, i was trying to access event hub data by running a sample application in spark streaming using eclipse ide in my local machine. When i tried setting a value as you mentioned it resulted in similar error only

Comment: I have created a storage and container. Spark am running through my local machine currently via eclipse  which is listening to event hub. Could you please guide me in setting the eventhubs.checkpoint.dir correctly